# Add a column After Get-AzureSqlDatabaseserver, Azure, PowerShell, Variable

Tags: powershell, variables, azure

when I execute this script, the result is like picture 1, first picture.

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "mysubscriptionname"  

Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer| export-csv -Path "C:\Users\km\Desktop\AzureProject\my.csv"-NoTypeInformation
```

I would like to add a column, for example, I1 = Subscription, I2=MYSUBSCription, I3=MYSUBSCription, I4=MYSUBSCription on my CSV

I would like to make my result like Picture 2, below.

How can I change the code to show like picture 2?

Thank you so much

[image: This is Picture 1]

[image: This is Picture 2]

So I changed like this

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Susco Pay-As-You-Go"  
#These are SQL Dataserver under 'Susco Pay-As-You-Go'
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Add-Member -MemberType  NoteProperty -Name "Subscription" -Value $SubscriptionName | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\ki\Desktop\AzureProject\Susco Pay-As-You-Go-SQLDataServer.csv"-NoTypeInformation
```

but It worked one time  after that code is not working, CSV file is empty.

so I tested like this

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Susco Pay-As-You-Go"  
#These are SQL Dataserver under 'Susco Pay-As-You-Go'
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer
```

There are data, so I do not know why it is not showing up on CSV.

SO I tried like this I made space between -path and -NoTypeInformation, There is no data on CSV.

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Susco Pay-As-You-Go"  
#These are SQL Dataserver under 'Susco Pay-As-You-Go'
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Add-Member -MemberType  NoteProperty -Name "Subscription" -Value $SubscriptionName | ConvertTo-Csv -Path "C:\Users\ki\Desktop\AzureProject\Susco Pay-As-You-Go-SQLDataServer.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

and I tried ConvertTo-Csv

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Susco Pay-As-You-Go"  
#These are SQL Dataserver under 'Susco Pay-As-You-Go'
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Add-Member -MemberType  NoteProperty -Name "Subscription" -Value $SubscriptionName | ConvertTo-Csv -Path "C:\Users\ki\Desktop\AzureProject\Susco Pay-As-You-Go-SQLDataServer.csv" -NoTypeInformation

ConvertTo-Csv : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Path'.
At line:3 char:129
+ ...  ConvertTo-Csv -Path "C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzureProject\Susco Pay-As-You- ...
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertTo-Csv], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToCsvCommand
```

It is causing error

I tried like this and the result was like this new photo

```
select-azuresubscription -SubscriptionName  "Susco Pay-As-You-Go"  
#These are SQL Dataserver under 'Susco Pay-As-You-Go'
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Add-Member -MemberType  NoteProperty -Name "Subscription" -Value $SubscriptionName  -PassThru | export-csv -Path "C:\Users\kazuakimai\Desktop\AzureProject\Susco Pay-As-You-Go-SQLDataServer.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

Comment: Can you use Add-Member? Something like:
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subscription" -Value $SubscriptionName | export-csv ...

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne   It worked one time,when I executed, after that it was not working anymore. Do you know why? I just want to add all my Get-azureVM, Get-Azurewebsite, and Get-AzureStorageAccount, I would like to ad my SubscriptionName.

Comment: I don't know why it would work once but not again. Do you want to edit your question to show the new test code and result?

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne. I did, Thank you so much. I am sure that It did one time and I did again, it doe not work, very strange... Thank you so much

Comment: I'll have a proper look at this later this evening. In the meantime I have two thoughts that might be worth investigating: First: Could the problem be as simple as a missing space? There is no space between the path and the -NoTypeInformation flag. Second: Try using ConvertTo-Csv instead of Export-Csv. That will put the CSV to the console so you can see what is happening. Maybe that will point to a problem.

Comment: @BrianO''Byrne I tried both, but It is still not working, Thank you so much for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Add-Member Cmdlet with the -PassThru option to get the desired result.

```
Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer | Add-Member -MemberType  NoteProperty -Name "Subscription" -Value $SubscriptionName -PassThru | export-csv -Path "~\Pay-As-You-Go-SQLDataServer.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It is really close but echoed out like new picture. please check. I edited it again.

Comment: I don't know what else I can tell you. I know this works having run it against my own Azure test environment. Are you sure you have set a valid value for $SubscriptionName?